# Change URL from a webpage or extension

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website and I have organised it in folders. This is my website http://www.harispapadakis.eu

I want to change for example this url http://www.harispapadakis.eu/menu/me.php to http://www.harispapadakis.eu/haris

If it's impossible, I'll be happy only to hide .php extension. I tried this via .htsaccess file but doesn't working for me.

This is my .htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.harispapadakis.eu/404.php

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^harispapadakis.eu [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.harispapadakis.eu/$1 [r=301,nc]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]


<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn on your `RewriteEngine`, do that by putting `RewriteEngine on` at the top of your .htaccess. The code to remove the .php extension is below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

To change `/menu/me.php` to `/haris`, you want to add the following lines to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^haris?$ /menu/me.php [NC,L]
```

It should do the trick for you. If it doesn't please tell me below in the comments. If I helped click that check. Have a good day.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I tried it but it's not working!!

Comment: @HarisPapadakis Works fine for me. [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/Wxml79E). If it still doesn't work, try `RewriteRule ^haris /menu/me.php [NC,L]`, but if it does work, please click that check.

Comment: @HarisPapadakis Great! Good job!